# Python Pandas: Find the difference of two dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, compare, difference

```
import pandas as pd

a = [0.0, 0.6900000000000001, 1.3800000000000001, 1.3800000000000001, 2.0700000000000003, 2.7600000000000002, 2.7600000000000002, 3.45, 4.1262, 4.140000000000001, 4.140000000000001, 4.83, 5.5200000000000005, 5.5200000000000005, 5.9754000000000005, 6.4308000000000005, 6.6654, 6.9]
b = [0.0, 0.6900000000000001, 1.3800000000000001, 1.3800000000000001, 2.0700000000000003, 2.7600000000000002, 2.7600000000000002, 3.45, 4.1262, 4.140000000000001, 4.140000000000001, 4.83, 5.5200000000000005, 5.5200000000000005, 5.9754000000000005, 6.4308000000000005, 6.4308000000000005, 6.6654, 6.9]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['x(m)'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(b, columns=['x(m)'])
```

df1:

```
      x(m)
0   0.0000
1   0.6900
2   1.3800
3   1.3800
4   2.0700
5   2.7600
6   2.7600
7   3.4500
8   4.1262
9   4.1400
10  4.1400
11  4.8300
12  5.5200
13  5.5200
14  5.9754
15  6.4308
16  6.6654
17  6.9000
```

df2:

```
      x(m)
0   0.0000
1   0.6900
2   1.3800
3   1.3800
4   2.0700
5   2.7600
6   2.7600
7   3.4500
8   4.1262
9   4.1400
10  4.1400
11  4.8300
12  5.5200
13  5.5200
14  5.9754
15  6.4308
16  6.4308
17  6.6654
18  6.9000
```

The difference of the two dataframes is `row 16 in df2 is not in df1`. How can I get the difference? The output can be the row index `16` plus the value `6.4308` , or a combined dataframe with the third column specifying `not in df1` or anything similar. Thanks.

Comment: 6.4308 is in both `df1` and `df2`. The logic is not clear to me.

Comment: @x_Amir_x: Compare row by row. See the answer below from Scott Boston.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, do you want something like this?

```
df1['seq'] = df1.groupby('x(m)').cumcount()
df2['seq'] = df2.groupby('x(m)').cumcount()
df1.merge(df2, how="outer", indicator="in_df")\
   .sort_values("x(m)")\
   .replace({"right_only": "not in df1", "left_only": "not in df2"})
```

Output:

```
      x(m)  seq       in_df
0   0.0000    0        both
1   0.6900    0        both
2   1.3800    0        both
3   1.3800    1        both
4   2.0700    0        both
5   2.7600    0        both
6   2.7600    1        both
7   3.4500    0        both
8   4.1262    0        both
10  4.1400    1        both
9   4.1400    0        both
11  4.8300    0        both
12  5.5200    0        both
13  5.5200    1        both
14  5.9754    0        both
15  6.4308    0        both
18  6.4308    1  not in df1
16  6.6654    0        both
17  6.9000    0        both
```

*Note:* [`pd.DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas-dataframe-merge) without the `on` defined will merge dataframes on all identical columns in the dataframe.  If you want to keep the indexing in both dataframes, `reset_index` first.

And, if you only one the difference then add `.query('in_df != "both"')`

Comment: Without the `on` in `merge` is the key point. Thanks.